# Getting issue with JSON mapping

Tags: java, jackson

I am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed exception when I try to mapp the response object to VO object using ObjectMapper

Code:

```
     */
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(apiUrl).post(body)
                .addHeader(CommunicationConstants.API_KEY, apiKey)
                .addHeader(CommunicationConstants.EMAIL_CONTENT_TYPE, contentType).build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        System.out.println("Error:"+response.body().string());
        falconideRes = mapper.readValue(response.body().string(), FalconideResponseVO.class);
        logger.info("Falconide Triggering call ends.");
```

public class FalconideResponseVO {

```
@JsonProperty("error_info")
private ErrorInfo errorInfo;
@JsonProperty("message")
private String message;

@JsonProperty("message")
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

@JsonProperty("message")
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
/**
 * @return the errorInfo
 */
@JsonProperty("error_info")
public ErrorInfo getErrorInfo() {
    return errorInfo;
}

/**
 * @param errorInfo the errorInfo to set
 */
@JsonProperty("error_info")
public void setErrorInfo(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
    this.errorInfo = errorInfo;
}
```

}

public class ErrorInfo {

```
@JsonProperty("error_message")
private String errorMessage;
@JsonProperty("error_code")
private Integer errorCode;

@JsonProperty("error_message")
public String getErrorMessage() {
return errorMessage;
}

@JsonProperty("error_message")
public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}

@JsonProperty("error_code")
public Integer getErrorCode() {
return errorCode;
}

@JsonProperty("error_code")
public void setErrorCode(Integer errorCode) {
this.errorCode = errorCode;
}
```

}

```
{"error_info":{"error_message":"Parameter [subject] not passed in the api call","error_code":113},"message":"Payload_Error"}
```

Need to map this to VO object. But when I do I am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed  exception

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `.string()` method twice. I believe you can do it only once since it's a terminate method - hence the "closed" exception.

To be more specific:

```
System.out.println("Error:"+response.body().string());
falconideRes = mapper.readValue(response.body().string(), FalconideResponseVO.class);
```

in the second line the `Stream` is closed. If you want to print it and then use in the other function of the `mapper` you should extract the variable before, like:

```
String variable = response.body().string();
System.out.println("Error:"+variable);
falconideRes = mapper.readValue(variable, FalconideResponseVO.class);
```

Comment: Not sure why this was not an accepted answer or not sure why this answer does not have any upvotes. I ran into the same issue and had hard time figuring out as the exception trace did not lead me anywhere. If not for this answer, I'd have wasted hours banging my head.